# What's a single word that means "group of branches"?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a system that allows users to group branches (stores/shops/outlets) of a company/franchise, but it has come to the attention of the team that not every English speaker may call them branches (although they're what we call them, but the system is global).

We wish to use a single word to refer to the "group of branches", but we're stumped.

To clarify, a group of branches is categorized by the users in however way they wish to categorize them, whether it is based by locations/shared preferences/properties, or anything in-between. For example, KFC may have a group with the following branches:

1. KFC in Country ABC City X Mall A (Food Court 1).
2. KFC in Country ABC City X Mall A (Food Court 3).
3. KFC in Country ABC City Z Block 123.
4. KFC in Country EFG City Y Block 456.

I'm providing the above example so that it is understood that the user is in control of grouping the branches, and there is no expected correlation that could help define the grouping (give the name). The only thing they have in common is the company/franchise that owns them.

One of my colleagues suggested "Area", while I suggested "Division". [The antonyms of branch are "whole" and "company"](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/branch). I was calling for "division" as a branch may be a "subdivision". Otherwise there's "aggregation", "collection", and "entity", which I didn't like, because we use that terminology for other things (internally), and they might sound too complex/vague for the average user. I'm still not sure what to actually call it, and where to search for other systems that have it already figured out.

Comment: Cluster. ...............

Comment: We just called them *stores*.  Stores were organized into districts and districts were organized into regions.

Comment: They’re the user’s favorites, aren’t they? Or “selected” stores.  Selections may overlap.

Comment: Well, a "group of branches" is a "tree", but I doubt that that suits your context.

Comment: How would you use the word in a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The word is *Location**s***, the plural of Location, but with details added to their names to normalize their descriptions. If not Locations you may as well choose from names for animal groups; gaggle of KFCs or flock of Burger Kings. Marvelous question for those with businesses and databases to track them. What entity/name do you give the field to designate the *KFC Where*.

Only an aside;
Uniformity and the ability to describe anything is what makes a database so powerful.

1. KFC, ABC, X, A, Upper
2. KFC, ABC, X, A, Lower
3. KFC, ABC, Z, East
4. KFC, ABC, Z, South

There can be only a few places (corporate headquarters) where such details need to be known of the *Location* that are not local and familiar to the vicinity. This is very similar to small villages in England where the address can take six steps or more; county, precinct, borough, village, street, apartment.